# Firestore getting Javascript Date instead of Timestamp

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I'm using `Angular 6` and `Firestore` to develop an application where I'm saving my dates as Javascript's `Date` object. The issue is that when I do `snapshotChanges()`, It returns a `Unix Timestamp` instead of the Date object that is in my database.

I searched the solutions online ([this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/726#issuecomment-385163921), [and this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1575#issuecomment-385092252)) and found this **config option** for Firestore:

`{ timestampsInSnapshots: false }`

I'm trying to apply this in my app component like this:

```
constructor(private _db: AngularFirestore) {
    _db.firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: false });
  }
```

But then I get this **error**:

`Firestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only call settings() before calling any other methods on a Firestore object.`

I've also tried to change the settings before calling `snapshotChanges()` but, that also does not have any effect on the behaviour.

Note: I'm also using `AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()`

**Update:**

I tried [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1575#issuecomment-388491790) and it gives me this error:

`@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.0.3): 
The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.`

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the required functionality by adding the following code to my app controlled.

```
constructor(private _db: AngularFirestore) {
  _db.firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: false });
  _db.firestore.enablePersistence();
}
```

Remember, Don't `AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()` if you intend to use the above code. Simply adding `AngularFirestoreModule` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, try calling `_db.app.firestore().settings({})` because you are making app wide changes/configurations. And since you have mentioned that you need offline support by `enablePersistence()`, try calling that in your component in this case, instead of root module, but after calling settings().

In your component :

```
constructor(private _db: AngularFirestore) {
    _db.app.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: false });
    _db.app.firestore().enablePersistence();
}
```

Comment: `Property app does not exist on AngularFirestore` and `_db.firestore(): there is no such function`.

Comment: Okk. What happens when you are doing ` _db.firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: false });` in your component and call `enablePersistence()` right after that?

Comment: I still get `Firestore has already been started` error. And If I do it in my appModule, I get the `AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK` error.

Comment: Actually, By calling `enablePersistence()` right after the settings in my `App Module` fixes the issue, but should I be worried about the breaking changes? What should I do to make it compatible?

Comment: That is odd. `app` should exists as you might see here in the source.

[angular2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/firestore/firestore.ts)

Please share your Firebase and AngularFire2 version. Also if possible your repo.

Comment: ` "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",`
`"firebase": "^5.0.3"`
`"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10"`

Comment: Well, the warning simply means the Firebase have been using Date() - this is the default behaviour. But is planning to change to Timestamp values by default soon. Since you are not using Timestamp, you are getting that warning.

Please follow this 2 important links to know more about it.

[issue726](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/726)

and 

[this](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1024)

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to change make `{ timestampsInSnapshots: false }` only for a single service while keeping offline persistence?

Comment: Could be possible if you are able to get `FirebaseApp` instance from `AngularFirestore` injectable service. I am not sure.